# How to define font to the current frame font size

Tags: beamer, fontsize, itemize

I have a Beamer template I defined (to be compatible with the guidelines of my organization) and bullet points have to have the same size, whatever the list level.

In the template, I went for the easiest (dumbest?) way to do that:

```
% Font size for items                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\normalsize}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\normalsize}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subsubbody begin}{\normalsize}
```

It works well, but when I change the font size locally on a slide, it is broken:

```
\begin{frame}{List test with another font size}
  \scriptsize

  \begin{itemize}
    \item first item
    \item second item
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

since the list elements then appear in `normalsize` instead of the desire font size.

Therefore, the question is: is there a way of setting the font size in `setbeamertemplate` so that it uses the current font size instead of a fix size?

**Edit**: full MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Font size for items                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\normalsize}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\normalsize}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subsubbody begin}{\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{List test with another font size}
  \scriptsize

  \begin{itemize}
    \item first item
    \item second item
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments, always make a small, but compilable test document. Having to puzzle your pieces together and add all the stuff necessary to compile it, takes 10 times longer than actually working on your problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz my bad, I did indeed posted my question too quickly and forgot my manners. I added a MWE. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for editing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first level item will automatically be in the surrounding font size, so just do nothing.

For the second and third level items, you can overwrite the default beamer font like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{size=}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{List test with another font size}
  \Tiny 
  test

  \begin{itemize}
    \item first item
    \item second item
      \begin{itemize}
        \item first item
        \item second item
          \begin{itemize}
            \item first item
            \item second item
          \end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]